# trying to stop handler in java

Tags: java, android

i am trying to stop this handler in my main activity, i put this code `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` but its not working
this is my code

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 3000;
    
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!accessibility) {
                //my code here "if the accessibility is off ask for accessibility"
            }
            if (accessibility) {
                //if the accessibility is on then stop handler and ask for permissions
                
                //Need to stop handler here
                // i put this code but not working
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        
                //then execute code here "ask for permissions"

            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
```

then app after asking for accessibility and i turn it on , app ask for permissions but its gone quickly then ask again and gone quickly and loop ..

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to turn it into an [mre] because right now it's really hard to understand what it is that isn't working. How do you *know* that it isn't working? What behaviour do you expect and which one do you observe?

Comment: ok man i modified it can you look at it again ? @JoachimSauer

Comment: its asking again and again for permissions so i think handler didnt stop here ,i need to stop it so ask for permissions one time not repeat it

Comment: No matter the outcome, you *always* post the handler again 3 seconds later, that's probably not what you want. There should be some kind of end-condition under which you *do not* trigger it again.

Comment: i need to always ask for accessability if its off and after the user turn it on stop asking and ask for permmisons, how can i do this, can you help me?

Comment: i used handler to ask for accessability every 3 seconds if its off , and when its on then stop handler and asking for permissions

Comment: put `handler.postDelayed(this, delay);` inside an else block in order to prevent it to loop when the `accessability` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in line `handler.postDelayed(this, delay);`.

Irrespective of `accessibility` flag, the line `handler.postDelayed(this, delay);` will ragister the event again.

To solve this do following:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 3000;
    
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (accessibility) {
                //if the accessibility is on then stop handler and ask for permissions
                
                //Need to stop handler here
                // i put this code but not working
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        
                //then execute code here "ask for permissions"

            }
            else/* accessibility is false */ {
                //my code here "if the accessibility is off ask for accessibility"
                
                
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }
    }, delay);
```